# C++ buffer overflow detection with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, buffer-overflow

I have enabled compile options /sdl (Enable Additional Security Checks) /GS (Buffer Security Check)

I am looking to detect a buffer overflow, however only on application exit do I get an exception from the following code

```
int main()
{
    int tmp[10];
    *(tmp + 10) = 10;
}
```

It doesn't give an exception when the line is executed that overflows the array, but it does throw the exception when the application exits.

Is it possible to manually trigger this check for overflow rather than having to exit the application?

Comment: You need larger arrays for `/GS` there is a minimum array size before buffer checks are enabled - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check?view=vs-2019  eg `int buf[2];` _"...declare arrays whose size is too small..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten Sounds like an _answer_...

Comment: you guys are fast...I did an edit to the case before I saw your answers, when I found out that it does throw the exception but just on application exit

Comment: ok it does seem to work with even 1 element arrays, but the check is performed when the function returns, I put the code into a function and on return of the function it gave the error, that is fine for me, no need to do a manual call